# JavaScript function Import not working

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

I am trying to import a function from a separate .js file. When I declare the import command the page is not executing the code. But when I delete the import command and execute a simple alert('Hello'), that thing is popping up on the page.

PROJECT STRUCTURE 
--Todo-app 
----js 
------two.js 
------main.js 
----index.html

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

two.js

```
export function one() {
    return 1 + 1;
}
```

main.js

```
import { one } from 'two';
alert(one());
```

Comment: Try to use './two'

Comment: Can you see in the console any errors messages with the import statement?

Comment: @MustafaMamun content of the two.js is given above

Comment: Sorry have not seen it before corrected it.

Comment: @NotBad4U there is nothing on the console

Comment: ES6 modules aren't supported in browsers (with the exception of Edge). The code needs to be transpiled with Babel.

Comment: You're right @estus

Comment: @estus Sounds about right!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The import and export statements is not implemented in any browsers natively at this time. You need to use a transpiler like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/)

But chrome and firefox can parse this statements `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import` but not support the module loading.

See MDN for more détails
[Reference Statements import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

Comment: ES6 modules have got experimental support in Edge https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Browser_compatibility

Comment: All modern browsers now support [JavaScript modules via script tag](https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module)

Comment: "You need to use a transpiler like Babel" — Babel is not a bundler. It can translate one module syntax into another, but it won't combine modules into a single script. Since browsers *do* support `import` and **don't** support `require`, using Babel is unhelpful (unless used in combination with a bundler).

Comment: This response is now out of date.