# Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use classes in pure JavaScript, so I'm facing the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" and can't solve it.

File1.js - Main file

```
import example from "./file2";

var test = new example();
```

File2.js - Class file

```
export default class example {
    constructor() {
        console.log("hello world");
    }
}
```

Comment: Browsers cannot process `import` so you would need to use something like Babel, short explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41662216/779600

Comment: This question seems to be about using import statements outside of the browser, so it's different from the linked questions.

Answer (score 43):

Add files with `type="module"`:

```html
<script src="file1.js" type="module" ></script>
```

Comment: I think the OP is trying to use pure javascript sans a browser. I am using Node.Js and am having the same problem as the OP.

Comment: "scripts": { "start": "babel-node server.js" } should work

Comment: what do you mean "add files with type="module".  What if you're not using a script?

Comment: @PositiveGuy There are ways to execute javascript code outside of `script` tags but they rather should be avoided. If you want to know all nuts and bolts of import statements please refer to one of many comprehensive javascript books such as exploringjs.com/es6.html

Comment: In case it is browser based, it is explained in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#applying_the_module_to_your_html

Answer (score 4):

A little late, but for newcomers to this quandary, you can convert both files to a module js `.mjs`. From there you can do what you were trying:

File1.mjs - Main file

```
import example from "./file2.mjs";
```

File2.mjs - Class file

```
export default class example {
    constructor() {
        console.log("hello world");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add `"type": "module"` in package.json