# ReactJS inside .NET framework project - Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, babeljs

I've tried to use reactJS inside .net framework MVC application.

View:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/ReactJS/test.jsx")
```

test.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';

import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const App = () => <div>Hello world!</div>;
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Message is not shown and the error is:

> test.jsx:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a
>   module

I don't understand why is this not working. I have included both react libraries and babel library.

Comment: Not marking as duplicate because I am not sure if it is, but this may be your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58357941/cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module

Comment: Did you ever have any luck with this?  I'm running into a very similar scenario with ReactJS.Net and .NET Core sample app.

Answer (score 0):

you can bundle up your file in BudleConfig.js

```
 bundles.Add(new BabelBundle("~/bundles/test").Include(
           ("~/Scripts/lib/Component/test.jsx"),
           ));
```

and then import this Bundler in your CSHTML inside Script

```
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/test");
 ReactDOM.render(
        React.createElement(test),
        document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

and you are good to go like that you can create and import JSX easily in existing MVC projects.

Answer (score -1):

In your View, instead of using 
`@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/ReactJS/test.jsx")`

you can try like this `<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ReactJS/test.jsx")"></script>` to create the referenced JavaScript file (test.jsx).