# Cannot reference classes in separate React JSX files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs.net

All I'm trying to do is split my React components into separate JSX files and be able to reference one from the other.  I'm using ReactJS.Net in a .NET Core 3.1 MVC project.  Chrome is up to date (v80).  I'm quite new to JS and React so assume there's something basic I don't know.

When I place the two classes within the same file, it works as expected.  ESLint reasonably suggests that I split components to separate files.  When I break them into two as shown with `import` and `export`, I get the following error when I try to run it:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

The error is on the `import` line at the top of test.jsx.  I'm assume my lack of understanding of where import goes and what constitutes a module is not helping.

Test.jsx looks like:

```
import SimpleItem from './js/SimpleItem';
// tried variations on:  <script type="module" src="./js/SimpleItem.jsx"></script>;

class SimpleContainer extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="simpleContainer">Word<SimpleItem /></div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<SimpleContainer />, document.getElementById('content'));
```

SimpleItem.jsx looks like:

```
class SimpleItem extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="simpleItem">I'm Simple!</div>
        );
    }
}

export default SimpleItem;
```

I've spent a maddening amount of time Googling, but either posts I've found don't seem to solve the problem or my ignorance isn't understanding what seems like it should be a dreadfully straightforward proposition in most any language since last century.

As a couple examples, [ReactJS inside .NET framework project - Cannot use import statement outside a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58907594/reactjs-inside-net-framework-project-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-mo) asks a similar question giving same error.  I'm attempting to split my components vs. importing React (probably the same principle though).  Suggestions led me to [ES6 modules in the browser: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47632562/es6-module-import-giving-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-identifier).  But that didn't address it.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: The accepted answer to that linked dupe will fix your issue.

Comment: @JaredSmith  Excellent!  I had a few misses.  1) I already had my test.jsx script tag but had missed adding type="module", instead 2) I had tried adding the child SimpleItem.jsx as a script of type module.  3) A lot of references led me to believe I should leave the extension off the import, but in this case it seems it really wants it.

Comment: There's a lot going on here: jsx is NOT directly consumable in the browser and must be run through a transformer first. That same transformer SHOULD also resolve all your import statements for you or fail at build time (i.e. compile time) if it can't. Now you *can* transform on the fly in the browser but it's not good practice to do so for the same reason you don't compile your C# code at runtime. So it depends on what your build pipeline looks like, but you shouldn't be using jsx sources directly in a script tag. As for the imports...

Comment: ...depending on how you are transforming you Typescript/JSX you can convert those to something a little less quirky. Because you *have* discovered a quirk: most transformers *don't* like the extension but when running native imports directly in the browser (i.e. script type="module") you need it. As for the error message, those are implementation-dependent. You still have the same underlying problem as the other question, and it still has the same answer.

Comment: @JohnSpiegel Can you please answer your own question in a more organized manner so others can understand what was going on.

Comment: @jibfashr  A good suggestion, but I can't add an answer since the post has been closed as a duplicate.