# How to add react to my existing node website?

Tags: reactjs

I built a react app and now I try to add to to my website which is created with nodejs. I use fastify as framework. Is it possible to add just my react app to a single page of my website in a specific div? I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html

Comment: I already tried that. But I receive the following error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"

Comment: Sounds like your question is really about that error then... [edit] your question to include the error and what research you've done into solving the error. For instance, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58357941/215552) has a title matching the error...