# Import React Does not Render Page

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to learn React.  The tutorial that I am following says that I need to import react using the following:

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
```

I am working in Visual Studio and I cannot get that to work (however, it does not throw any errors).  The Visual Studio React tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-nodejs-with-react-and-jsx?view=vs-2019) told me to add the following to include React:

```
declare var require: any

var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
```

This works and my "Hello World!"  is rendered.  What I'd like to understand, is why the "import React" code does not work and what is the difference between the two. I'm not sure what other info someone would need to answer/explain my question, but I can provide more info if needed.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`import` statements are not supported natively yet in javascript. Have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41662017/javascript-function-import-not-working) where the answer is basically also answering what you are looking for.

If you don't want to bother about learning more about webpack/babel for now (I would highly recommend to skip this first and just focus on react), have a look at [create-react-app](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html) which handles all configuration for you. Also, there is a ton on material and tutorials regarding learning react with create-react-app.