# HTML & Three.js Canvas not showing up on page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, three.js, gsap

I'm trying to learn how to use three.js but in my html file, the  tag won't show up on my page.

Here's my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Three JS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas class="webgl"></canvas>
    <script src="/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's my javascript code:

```
import * as THREE from 'three'

const scene = new THREE.Scene()

const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(3, 64, 64)
const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
    color: '#00ff83'
})
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
scene.add(mesh)

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45)
scene.add(camera)

const canvas = document.querySelector(".webgl")
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas})
renderer.setSize(800, 600)
renderer.render(scene, camera)
```

I know that the camera and object are on the same spot, but I still should be seeing a black square for my canvas. Any ideas?

Comment: What is shown in the console?

Comment: Would you like to know what appears in the VSCode console or site console from inspect element?

Comment: I want to know if your browser's console displays a warning or error.

Answer (score 0):

Two items need to changes.

#1 source `CDN` is more common instead of using [`import`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41662017/javascript-function-import-not-working)

#2 camera - I don't know about `PespectiveCamera` but your setting is not working.
I copied from [here](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Creating-a-scene).

#### HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Three JS</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/0.148.0/three.min.js"></script>
    <canvas class="webgl"></canvas>
    <script src="./main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

#### Script code as `main.js`

```
const scene = new THREE.Scene()

const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(3, 64, 64);
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: '#00ff83'
});
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000); // updated
scene.add(camera)

const canvas = document.querySelector(".webgl")
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas})
renderer.setSize(800, 600)
camera.position.z = 5;  // added
renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

#### Result in VS code with [`live server`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer)

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Also, what does the cloudflare script tag in index.html do?

Comment: One of CDN provider. I copied [here](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/three.js)

Comment: It may be help to understand CDN https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/cdn/what-is-a-cdn/

Comment: Sorry I'm fairly new to web dev and don't understand what CDN is so thanks for providing a link.

Comment: No problem, it is important keep learning not  a how long experience. Enjoy your web learning start.